# HDD: Process and mitigation of digital decay / data degradation

Tags: hard-drive, storage

I am trying to find a long-term method of storing RAW photos. I'd like to keep it as simple as possible, while minimizing data loss (obviously a balance needs to be struck).

I currently archive my photos on two HDDs that are only running once a week or so which. Both drives are backed and kept in a different location. For day to day purposes I use an SDD.

My biggest concern is the ongoing degradation ("digital decay") on the HDDs, rather than mechanical failure.

**My question**

I understand one way to mitigate digital decay is to rewrite the files on the HDD every so often (let's say once per year). Is this a viable strategy to keep my photos safe long-term and can you provide sources for your answer?

Comment: There are no rules on the lifetime of a disk, it's all a matter of the disk's quality and just the luck of the draw.

Comment: Describe in more detail the purpose of the 2 hdd's, are they 'mirrors'? Note that this topic can fill a book and is bound to introduce different viewpoints and opinions.

Comment: From the OP: 
- The two HDDs hold the various files. They are not mirrors.
- That being said, I should add to the original query: I have all files backed up on a separate set of HDDs (in a different physical location). This is why I'm less worried about a mechanical failure. But digital decay is what's on my mind (which will affect all HDDs).

Comment: OP does not say that, it's not how I read it. And also I do not mean to criticize you, but I am warning you that in it's current form the question may not meet SuperUser guidelines. There are already 3 close votes, and think it would be shame if the question is closed as the topic is one that I think enough people have questions about or worry about. See https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I edited question in hopes it may meet SuperUser guidelines. I am a bit of a wandering soul my self with regards to that as well.

Comment: This is an opinion-based question. The scope is too large.
https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask
"Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: @Joepvansteen your edit entirely changes the question in a way which encourages wrong answers and hides the OP's goal.

Comment: @davidgo Voting encouraged me to edit the question rather than downvoting which i did the best I could to make it meet guidelines (focus, try inviting fact based answers etc.). IMO the central worry was corruption through decay and I think the question reflects this.

Comment: @davidgo, I posted a topic in meta and I welcome an explanation, https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15019/looking-to-learn-from-this-first-time-i-edited-question-other-than-in-lining-a

Answer (score 2):

If you are particularly worried about digital decay, then a NAS running ZFS can periodically check and fix decay.

There are other ways, but they are likely more cumersome. (Something like par under Linux can create parity and redundancy that can recover from bit rot, but it sounds like thats not where you want to go.

If you have multiple copies of the data and it changes infrequently you may be able to write software that stores checksums of the files and periodically checks these, advising if any have changed and need attention.

I confess to being confused about you being worried about digital decay bit not mechanical failure. Mechamical failure is a much bigger risk.

Comment: Data scrubbing is not limited to ZFS - data scrubbing is available on Linux and Windows given an appropriate storage arrangement. I expect it is also available on other OSen.

Comment: @andrewmorton - It may be useful to mention the tools/disk layouts.  I discovered btrfs can also do this as can dm-integrity.  How about Windows? (btw ZFS works as a Linux solution - that may not be clear from your post)

Comment: Apparently it's known as "data integrity scan" on Windows. I said Linux because arrays using [mdadm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mdadm) can also be scrubbed, from what I can see. Also, hardware RAID controllers can perform data scrubbing. [Wikipedia: Data scrubbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scrubbing)

Answer (score 2):

Digital decay is often a topic that's poorly understood IMO and as long as this is the case it's hard to compile answers that specifically address the issue.

This isn't a scientific answer but based on my own research and if desired I can back some of it with sources such as ATA specs and Intel conference footage, but I didn't due to lack of time.

Now 'decay' at the physical level, or loss of properties or a state of the material that allow us to store data in the first place can ultimately result in 'bit-flips'. This is basically what we're discussing, the root cause of our photos (or files in general) 'corrupting'.

### Bit flips

A corrupt photo on a hard drive is enough for many to diagnose 'bitrot' or 'magnetic decay'. And it's true a single 'bitflip' is enough to corrupt a photo depending on how the format stores data. In below example I change &hFE to &hFF and back (11111110 to 11111111) to demonstrate this.

[image]

### Detecting bit flips

However we then need to consider if this happening is a theoretical possibility and the theoretical answer is no. To explain this we need to understand how a hard drive stores data and what mechanisms are in place to protect this data.

[image]

I will skip the actual physics of how data is stored on hard drives, first because I am no expert on the matter and second it should be enough to understand that hard drives do not store zeros and ones, but interpret physical properties or measurements as zeros or ones. And at the physical level, physical factors can change these.

To guard against this hard drives employ error correction that allows us to detect errors and to a degree correct them. We call this ECC commonly. Simplified, if we write a block of data to a drive, we do not only write the data but we also write an ECC block to the drive that was computed using this data. And if we read back, we again compute the ECC over the data we read and compare this to the ECC we stored at the time of writing the data.

If we now assume data is corrupted to a degree where we can no longer ECC correct it, whether this is due to 'decay' or some other issue then *any* protocol I know of of will report a **read error**. IOW, a photo as shown in previous paragraph theoretically can not occur due to 'decay'. Because if we assume decay we should get a read error, not a corrupt file.

And yet, these things, photos such as shown above, do occur and the assumption often is that this is due to decay or bit rot, which I argued, they're not the result of.

Please understand that I do not claim there's no such thing as 'decay'. I am just saying that things we often label as a result of decay aren't. And to safe guard against something it may help understand what we're actually dealing with.

### So then how can we explain such 'bit-rotten' photos?

If corruption as shown above can not be explained by decay, it is has to introduced at a different point. If the data and the ECC 'agree' on the data then

- they were written as is, IOW the corruption was introduced before the data was written
- they are corrupted at some point after they were read from the drive.

This may happen more often than we think and I'd like to give a few examples to illustrate:

**First one non hard drive example:** I was asked to repair corrupt CR2 photos that were copied from a CF flash memory card. I assumed 'decay' which is very common in NAND chips: Simplified a NAND cell is injected with electrons resulting in a certain charge, let's call it y. if y > x, where x is a threshold which determines if we interpret the cell as zero or one, we read 1, if y < x we read zero.

Over time y will drop, this can not be avoided and so if we wait long enough it will drop below x and we have a bit flip. However, since CF flash cards are actually ATA drives, bit flips per sector will be ECC detected and/or corrected so we either get correct(ed) data or no data at at all and a read error. IOW since there are no read-errors when reading the RAW photos we can not assume bit errors as a result of decay. Again, the origin of the error lies somewhere else.

[image]

Another hint to the fact we weren't dealing with decay was that the bitflips occurred in a pattern. In each photo it was the same bits that got flipped, each time for example 'Canon' inside the file's header had changed into 'Cankn':

```
Canon - Cankn
01101111 - o changed into
01101011 - k
     ^   - flipped bit
```

It turned out to be the physical interface that introduced 'noise' that caused corrupt data to be written and the ECC to be computer over already corrupted data.

**Second example** of where it was assumed 'decay' caused the observed corruption of digital photos:

[image]

Case was solved and intact photos were recovered as it turned out the file system was corrupt resulting in picking wrong clusters to be assigned to files. So again no 'decay'.

**And as a third example**, [Intel that assumes](https://youtu.be/fqzv2YXMFRs) one of the larger contributors to silent corruption in SSD's is cosmic rays but not as you might expect it.

When I first heard about these 'cosmic rays', I assumed that ions and protons knocked electrons out of NAND cells causing bits to flip, but this was not the case!

Again, if this were the case, such errors should be detected by ECC. Whether it is the actual data or the ECC code itself being affected it would result in a discrepancy between the ECC and the data and thus produce a read error.

As you may know, modern SSD's do all kinds of back ground processing, move data from one place to the other, and during these processes data is briefly placed in volatile RAM memory. And this is where the data is 'altered' by the cosmic rays and that causes corrupt data to be re-written with the matching ECC.

What's important to take from this, that the corruption isn't introduced while the data is 'stored', but while it's being transported and temporarily stored in RAM, so the exact same thing might happen in mechanical hard drives.

### Long story short

What we often perceive to the result of 'decay' often isn't, instead it's different factors that explain file corruption.

Corruption that is a result of decay should be detected (and corrected if possible) by the drive itself. This is as true for magnetic hard drives as it is for SSD's.

You can try to detect 'silent corruption', bit rot or whatever you want to call it by adding an additional layer of **check-summing**. Some file systems as already suggested in another answer implement check-sums as a core feature.

Since a checksum is computed *after* the data is written, we assume the data is correct and intact to begin with.

**Refreshing or scrubbing** is often suggested. It is true that refreshing data, the simple fact of reading data and writing it back helps prevent 'bit-rot'. At the same time we see that Intel identifies silent corruption can happen during the auto-refreshing of data as it is implemented on many SSD's. The same would apply to a user application that reads and writes back data to a mechanical hard drive.

I must add that the chance that refreshing data by re-writing is astronomically small and that it is far more likely to do good (refresh data) than bad. The example was primarily to demonstrate that such events can introduce silent corruption, but not that it is likely.

**Eventually the only answer is backups.** There are many possible causes for data loss, and although decay or silent corruption or bit rot can occur it may unwise to focus on it exclusively. It's good to be aware of it though and the fact that detecting it is the main challenge. **Check-summing** is a partial answer as it can help detect changes to files since the moment they were written.

**With regards to life-times:**

The way I understand it, we're dealing with statistics. There's no law that says you're data will be useless after 3 - 5 years, it's a simple statistic that says your drive will last for x years, with y average use per day or whatever, under z conditions. But since it's statistics, your hard drive may fail tomorrow.

You can probably store a hard drive for 10 years without decay being an issue. Perhaps a bigger issue is the mechanics and moving parts being inactive for such a period.

Comment: To ultra fast downvoter: care to explain? I mean I put some time and effort into this, maybe you could too?

Comment: Dear Joep,

Thank you very much for your in depth answer and also for kindly amending my original question. I found this very informative.

I now realise that when I used the term "digital decay" it might have been misleading. What I had in mind was less actually decaying photos, but the idea that "bit flips" would cause my photos to be corrupted. However, you have somewhat alleviated my fear of this happening.

I also find it interesting that re-writing may actually do more harm than good. 

If you want to expand on these notions, I would appreciate it. Otherweise, thank you again!

Comment: I will rephrase that. I think that refreshing is more likely to good than harm. It was mostly meant to illustrate that is actually a point where corruption can be introduced but the chance for it happening is astronomically small.

Comment: Excellent answer (as usual). It's probably worth mentioning that for DDR4 and older RAM modules don't have mandatory ECC and many (most?) desktop platforms even don't support it at all (it's very common in servers though). Starting with DDR5, ECC is mandatory

Answer (score 0):

> My question
>
> I understand one way to mitigate digital decay is to rewrite the files
> on the HDD every so often (let's say once per year). Is this a viable
> strategy to keep my photos safe long-term and can you provide sources
> for your answer?

Think of your hard drive as a carpet, at the end of its life span it has holes in it and those holes can not be repaired.

As @Joep van Steen mentions hard drives have ECC, and that corrects errors up to a point of so many bad bits.  I don't know what the threshold is but after it is crossed, the sector is bad and its contents are considered lost.

The hard drive does provide SMART (Self monitoring And Reporting Tool).  This tool will provide a variety of statistics.  Among these values are bad sector and ECC values.

Now these statistics have 1 flaw they only report on the sectors they touch.  So unless you periodically do a chkdsk /r (or similar) you won't get a complete picture of the status of the whole drive. However tools like smartctl which display the SMART data will give you some indication as to the health of the drive.

You can recopy your data, and that refresh it but if the sector its on is weak it may lose its ability to store data and eventually be marked bad.

So you need to scan the whole drive, and monitor the ECC corrected sectors.  When the drive is new the value should be 0, and should remain so for a year or more.  The biggest concern is the rate of increase, having a handful of ECC correcting isn't a big deal.  However, eventually the drive will have 1000's and more.  At this point the only safe choice is drive replacement.

Back to answering your question.  The generally accept as safe strategy is 3-2-1 backup.  3 copies in 2 location at 1 time.  For example: your main drive, external drive, and a cloud backup.

Above that the cost rises dramatically.  RAID 6 offers the best compromise between protection and cost.  RAID 60 (6 plus drive mirroring) requires 2x the number of hard drives, and thus costs even more.  RAID 6 requires a minimum of 4 drives, and you can lose up to 2 drives at once and you won't lose any data.

You will need a RAID controller, and although they exist at $200-$300 price point the good ones are more like $1200.  Plus the cost of the drives, and depending on how many drives you have you may need a larger case and power supply.

On top of the RAID you can implement ZFS or btrfs for an extra layer of protection, but you would need to run linux as windows doesn't support these file systems directly.

---

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       40490
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       555
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       9
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   059   045   000    Old_age   Always       -       41
195 ECC_Error_Rate          0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 CRC_Error_Count         0x003e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
235 POR_Recovery_Count      0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       381
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       18507464781


SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   137   137   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       79
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   193   193   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       329 (Average 317)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       8107
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   140   140   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       26
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       38719
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       511
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       8309
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       8309
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   153   153   000    Old_age   Always       -       39 (Min/Max 10/56)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

Comment: "monitor the ECC corrected sectors." How?!
A correctable sector will read out normally without notice.

Comment: @r2d3 For windows, you need to google and install smartctl.  Linux also has a program for this.  Then smartctl -a /dev/sda  .  If you have multiple drives replace a with b,c,d, or etc depending on how many drives you have installed.  However, this is not the only program, and there are dozens of programs which will let you see the SMART data.

Comment: @Cybernard: This was an extremely helpful answer, thank you very much.

I just researched a bit more on how to interpret SMART data. This now seems like a great way to monitor the health of my hard drives.

One final question: Could you kindly explain again what to do in order to get reliable SMART data? You said simply reading-out SMART wasn't enough, but that running chkdsk might be necessary before.

Comment: checking SMART wont help you at all with respect of your stated goal to prevent bit rot - its designed to try predict mechanical/chip failure  and cant detect bitrot.  This is an answer to the question as it currently stands, but someone edited it to the point the question now bears no resemblance to what was asked.

Comment: This answer starts by quoting the question as it currently is in verbatim.

Comment: Of course it will, 'bit rot' (not mentioned in the question BTW) or 'decay' will eventually produce ECC errors and trigger ECC correction.

Comment: Cybernard, you did not get my point. I know SMART, smartmontools and operate your proposed command pretty regularly. Where can I monitor ECC data, please? ECC correction takes place long before an error shows up, for instance as a pending sector. I would like to monitor the operation of ECC, not SMART attributes. I just looked acrossed some saved SMART reports, the term "ECC" does not appear in any of those. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a "Raw_Read_Error_Rate"?  What attributes do you have?  The drive updates the SMART attributes in real time.  However, actually monitoring ECC in real time is beyond any software that I have experienced.  However, expensive forensics software might have access to the inner workings.  These devices which are typically hardware and software and very expensive and nothing something I would buy for fun.

Comment: On modern hard drives and certainly SSD's continuous ECC correction is part of normal operation. I suppose publishing RT ECC correction activity would scare the sh*t of people. Pending would imply ECC correction failed. If drive decides to reallocate on it's own, it's only after it could ECC correct or recover data from a 'questionable' sector. Problem with SMART is that every manufacturer decides what he monitors exactly in a certain attribute, various error counters in Seagates already spook people because they're not strictly counting errors.

Comment: On rereading the question you talk about RAID with ZFS on top.  You should not run ZFS on top of RAID particularly because RAID abstracts away the hard drive and will make picking up bit rot harder/impossible.

Comment: One does not need a RAID controller to use RAID - software RAID is a thing and you're not locked in to RAID controller's proprietary format. ZFS on hardware RAID is counterproductive. The tight integration of filesystem, checksumming and software RAID in ZFS results in better performance and ability to automatically recover in scenarios where traditional RAID would require manual intervention and substantial effort. With btrfs unfortunately one should use separate RAID (hardware or software) because its RAID5/6 is not production-ready.

Answer (score 0):

I love the details provided in the answer of *Joep van Steen*.

I'd like to add some other items to the list of risks of data loss, especially consumer users have to deal with:

1. Hidden planned obsolescence
   I've seen this on HDDs, cheap notebooks and mobiles; all of them produced by well known and well acknowledged manufacturers in their consumer line, but I have not yet been aware of this in the business line of their products. Often the "failure" is triggered by code and not by physical wear. So the to trust the hardware can just be for the time of warranty. Every additional day you have to feel as a bonus time.
   Note, this is no "urban legend". I still have most of these items in my possession.
2. Do not count an active SSD as a valid backup media.
   I noticed data holes (multiple successive bytes vanished) in files (i.e. pictures) that have not been touched for a long time. A second copy of the same set of files on the same SSD had similar holes but at different positions, so a merge of both resulted in a valid set.
3. Surely  an obvious and trivial fact: The risk of ransomware and user handling failures are also a problem to take into account.

---

The practical consequence of this:
Despite of any technical deep dive into the reliability of hardware and their countermeasures against failures like ECC and similar strategies or filesystem specifica,  you always have to deal with the risk, that your media potentially will lose data or fail at an event you do not expect.

To limit the the answer tight to your question and your current state of backup:

I think you should enhance your backup strategy at least by these points:

- Maintain a checksum list (i.e. SHA256SUM).
- HDDs of different production lines and different age (to face the increasing risk of failure due to aging and possible systematic production issues. Evaluating the S.M.A.R.T. information will help you to know when to exchange a HDD).
- You should have scripts or a tool that will handle the necessary routines automatically (reliability, reproducible results).

To just verify the integrity of your backup data, you check the checksums on a regular basis

To prevent the decay of your data, you

1. copy the data one by one,
2. verify the checksum of the new copy and
3. on checksum success you delete the old file.
4. You verify the S.M.A.R.T. data for problematic values.

The second HDD has its own decay prevention cycle in the same style, time-shifted to the first one.

By this "file-by-file" strategy you always have two backup versions of a file available and are not required to maintain a huge swap space.
But you could also just (1) do a copy to a third backup HDD and (2) do the whole checksum verification in the next step. (3) You keep track of the S.M.A.R.T. data of both HDDs. (4) Then (on success) the first HDD becomes the new "third HDD" (destination for the next decay prevention copy).

Any reliable information about the risk of decay and lifetime for consumer products cannot be expected. You should assume the warranted life time as maximum.
My personal opinion for HDDs is that a one year cycle is quite short (low risk), a two year cycle probably would also fit, when ignoring the risk of "planned obsolescence" . But I think there is hardly any reason why not keep the risk low and do an annual decay cycle. As the task really should be automated, the used time cannot be an issue.

At an annual cycle, the integrity verification and the decay prevention are joined in one task.

Additionally useful extensions would be

- a separate geographic location of a third backup of your data. (resulting in a kind of "3-2-1 backup. 3 copies in 2 location at 1 time." as *cybernard* already has suggested) to prevent elementary issues like total destruction of your home/office by fire/water/tornado/...
- a separate system for the backup handling to isolate the backup routines and data from the daily business and risk (a "Raspberry PI" or similar would be enough).

Comment: "I noticed data holes" - This is super interesting. Were the drives connected to power during their 'not being touched period'?

Comment: No, this  has been an actively used SSD, not a backup drive. But the specific data has not been touched for a long time. — That's why I wrote "*active* SSD"

Comment: I see. It would suggest silent corruption either due to something seemingly far fetched as cosmic rays, but abrupt shutdowns can also cause this type of issues with SSD's. Of the latter hints could be found by examining the SMART data. basically SSD's detect ungraceful shutdowns similar to Windows using some 'dirty flag' and report those to SMART.

Comment: I didn't dare to speculate about the reason for this. – The SMART test PASSED,  no errors // `Wear_Leveling_Count`: `VALUE=98`, `RAW=33` // `POR_Recovery_Count`: `VALUE=99`, `RAW=86` // Other values are without change or at expected regular usage. So the aging of the SSD with several years of usage is fine and no reason visible for the loss of bytes. — *Exactly such a scenario tells me, not to just rely on sane technical risk values but to expect the unexpected and establish a data save guard system that personally I can handle, understand and know how to solve upcoming issues on my own.*